# Set Negative Values to Zero for raster in arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I have a DEM layer containing floating point data. 
I am using the following code to convert the negative values to 0 in arcpy.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:\mmrahm

out = Con("cnph" < 0.0, 0.0, "cnph")
```

The code runs fine and a raster layer named "out"  is created. However, the negative values are still there, i.e., the output layers remain identical to the input layer.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I also tried the following code
outCon = Con("cnph", "cnph", 0.0, "Value < 0")